# functions in seurat to calculate the gene count per cluster

Tags: r, gene, seurat, single-cell

I'm running FindAllMarkers

```
markers <- FindAllMarkers(scData_scTransform_PTX_only_res04_20PC_6000g_30mt_sb_removal_20210713_ann_exp0_counts, min.pct = 0.25, logfc.threshold = 0.25)
```

But was wondering if there is a function in seurat to get the raw (non-normalized) expression data from each cell type cluster

Comment: Hi, could you please add more context to this question so that we can understand why you want to find out this information? I've calculated *cell* counts per cluster, and visualised gene counts per cluster using scatter plots, but haven't yet run into a case where I'd need to work out *gene* count per cluster as a single statistic (whatever that means).

Comment: @mmpp could it be that you meant to compare expression profiles of some genes (by means of a boxplot, for instance), to evaluate the differences between two conditions, in the same cell type, i.e. a cluster?

Comment: are you trying to calculate pseudobulk average?